# At what point in Amazon Connect flow will $.Agent.UserName be set?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

In a custom Amazon Connect contact flow, I am using `$.Agent.UserName` to grab the Agent's login name.  Here is a snapshot from `Edit settings` for a `Set contact attributes` flow block:

[image]

I've wired up a Lambda function that triggers *before* `Set working queue` or `Transfer to queue` flow blocks; said Lambda function reads the contact attribute `agentUsername`, but it is consistently empty -- presumably because the call at this point of the flow has not been routed to a specific agent.

QUESTION:  Is there a specific recommendation for where in the Amazon Connect contact flow we can expect the contact attribute `$.Agent.UserName` to be set?

Answer (score 0):

From https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/adminguide/connect-attrib-list.html#attribs-agent

Agent attributes are available only in the following types of flows:

- Agent whisper
- Customer whisper
- Agent hold
- Customer hold
- Outbound whisper
- Transfer to agent. In this case, the agent attributes reflect the target agent, not the one who initiated the transfer.

Agent attributes are not available in the following flow types:

- Customer queue
- Transfer to queue
- Inbound flow

Comment: In the admin dashboard for Amazon Connect, you cannot align a phone number with something other than a `Contact flow`.  So we now have a catch-22:  use a flow for which Agent attributes are accessible, but do not align that flow with a phone #; use a Contact flow for which Agent attributes are NOT accessible, and align that flow with a phone number.

Comment: No we don't have a catch 22. Connect can't tell you which agent is being targeted before they are being targeted. Agents are only being targeted in the flow types listed.

If you are wanting to target an agent based on the dialled number, then you will need to do a lookup of some sort, probably from a DynamoDB, to get the agent's ID, then use the Set working queue block to set the queue "By agent" and set the agent